# Is DHCP client of any use on my desktop computer?

Tags: linux, dhcp

Is DHCP client of any use on my desktop computer?

I use my computer mainly for office purposes (web browsing/media consuming/libre office).

As I am setting up some firewall rules, I wish to restrict any process that is not useful.

Comment: Are you talking about a DHCP server or client? Even so, the answer strongly depends on your network environment. If you can control the IP addresses of all networked devices in your network, you do not really _need_ DHCP, but it can make management a lot easier.

Comment: adresses assignement is usually done by ADSL modem or equivalent. I can't see any casual need for DHCP server for home computer.

Comment: @Adminbee, I am talking about DHCP client (question edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have configured static IP addresses for your computer, you will need the DHCP-client to get an IP address from your network: your Fritzbox, your cable-modem, or somesuch.

Try and disable the dhcp-client and see what happens :-)
(Disable, not deinstall!)

Answer (score 2):

In very nearly all typical end-user configurations, network configuration of the host is done via DHCP.  If you disable the DHCP Client (or block DHCP traffic with your host's firewall), it's exceedingly likely that your computer will still function, but anything requiring network connectivity will not.